# what does lst[:] = [1,2,3] mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a little bit confused. What exactly does [:] in this code do when used with an assignment?

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [1, 2, 3]

def test(l1, l2):
    l1 = [0]
    l2[:] = [0]

test(l1, l2)
# l1 = [1, 2, 3]
# l2 = [0]
```

When I use l2[:] = [0], is it like:

```
def test(l1, l2):
    global l1
    l1 = [0]
    l2 = [0]
```

Or does it have another meaning?
Thank you!

Comment: What is the point of `text`?

Comment: just a mistake :) meant to be test

Comment: They are very different.  This is not a scope issue, so `global` has nothing to do with it.  `l1[:] = [0]` modifies the list `l1` by setting it to `[0]`.  That is, it replaces all existing elements with the single element `0`, but it does *not* create a new list.  It modifies the existing list, so all references to that list will reflect the change.

Comment: So basically it looks for l1 in the scope to modify. If it cannot find l1, it looks for it outside the scope?

Comment: Python uses a fairly simple set of scope resolution rules.  If a variable is assigned to within a function body, then that variable is local to that function (unless declared `global` or `nonlocal`).  If it is accessed, but not assigned to, then it looks in the current scope, and if absent, looks in a higher-level scope.  But note that `x = y` assigns to the variable `x`, while `x[:] = [y]` does not.  The latter modifies what `x` refers to, but does not modify `x` itself.